# How orderBy affects Window.partitionBy in Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, window, sql-order-by

I explain my question through an example:
Let us assume we have a dataframe as follows:

```
original_df = sc.createDataFrame([('x', 10,), ('x', 15,), ('x', 10,), ('x', 25,), ('y', 20,), ('y', 10,), ('y', 20,)], ["key", "price"] )
original_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|key|price|
+---+-----+
|  x|   10|
|  x|   15|
|  x|   10|
|  x|   25|
|  y|   20|
|  y|   10|
|  y|   20|
+---+-----+
```

And assume I want to get a list of `prices` for each `key` using `window`:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('key')
original_df.withColumn('price_list', F.collect_list('price').over(w)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|      price_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   10|[10, 15, 10, 25]|
|  x|   15|[10, 15, 10, 25]|
|  x|   10|[10, 15, 10, 25]|
|  x|   25|[10, 15, 10, 25]|
|  y|   20|    [20, 10, 20]|
|  y|   10|    [20, 10, 20]|
|  y|   20|    [20, 10, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------+
```

So far so good.
But if I want to get an ordered list, and I add `orderBy` to my window `w` I get:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy('price')
original_df.withColumn('ordered_list', F.collect_list('price').over(w)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|    ordered_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   10|        [10, 10]|
|  x|   10|        [10, 10]|
|  x|   15|    [10, 10, 15]|
|  x|   25|[10, 10, 15, 25]|
|  y|   10|            [10]|
|  y|   20|    [10, 20, 20]|
|  y|   20|    [10, 20, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------+
```

Which means `orderBy` (kind of) changed the rows (same as what `rowsBetween` does) in the window as well! Which it's not supposed to do.

Eventhough I can fix it by specifying `rowsBetween` in the window and get the expected results,

```
w = Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy('price').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

can someone explain why `orderBy` affects `window` in that way?

Comment: In addition to @Manjoi Singh's excellent answer, this is btw. how you get the list of prices, as expected: `original_df.groupBy("key").agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_list("price")).alias("prices"))` with `F` being `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spark Window are specified using three parts: partition, order and frame.

1. When none of the parts are specified then whole dataset would be considered as a single window.
2. When partition is specified using a column, one window per distinct value of the column is created. If only partition is specified, then when a when is evaluated for a row, all the rows in that partition would taken into account. Thats why you see all 4 values [10, 15, 10, 25] for all the rows in partition x.
3. When partition and ordering is specified, then when row function is evaluated it takes the rank order of rows in partition and all the rows which has same or lower value (if default asc order is specified) rank are included. In your case, first row includes [10,10] because there 2 rows in the partition with the same rank.
4. When Frame specification rowsBetween and rangeBetween are specified, then row evaluation would pick only those rows which matched frame rule. e.g. unbounded and currentRow is specified it would pick current row and all rows that occur before it. If orderBy is specified, it would change which rows occur before the current row accordingly.

specifically to your question, orderBy is not only to sort the partitioned data but it also change the row frame selection

Below are different windowspec and the corresponding output

```
Window.orderBy()
+---+-----+----------------------------+
|key|price|price_list                  |
+---+-----+----------------------------+
|x  |15   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
|x  |10   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
|y  |10   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
|y  |20   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
|x  |10   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
|x  |25   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
|y  |20   |[15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 25, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------------------+

Window.partitionBy('key')
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|      price_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   15|[15, 10, 10, 25]|
|  x|   10|[15, 10, 10, 25]|
|  x|   10|[15, 10, 10, 25]|
|  x|   25|[15, 10, 10, 25]|
|  y|   20|    [20, 10, 20]|
|  y|   10|    [20, 10, 20]|
|  y|   20|    [20, 10, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------+

Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy('price')
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|    ordered_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   10|        [10, 10]|
|  x|   10|        [10, 10]|
|  x|   15|    [10, 10, 15]|
|  x|   25|[10, 10, 15, 25]|
|  y|   10|            [10]|
|  y|   20|    [10, 20, 20]|
|  y|   20|    [10, 20, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------+

w = Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy(F.desc('price'))
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|    ordered_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   25|            [25]|
|  x|   15|        [25, 15]|
|  x|   10|[25, 15, 10, 10]|
|  x|   10|[25, 15, 10, 10]|
|  y|   20|        [20, 20]|
|  y|   20|        [20, 20]|
|  y|   10|    [20, 20, 10]|
+---+-----+----------------+

Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy('price').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|    ordered_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   10|            [10]|
|  x|   10|        [10, 10]|
|  x|   15|    [10, 10, 15]|
|  x|   25|[10, 10, 15, 25]|
|  y|   10|            [10]|
|  y|   20|        [10, 20]|
|  y|   20|    [10, 20, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------+

Window.partitionBy('key').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
+---+-----+----------------+
|key|price|    ordered_list|
+---+-----+----------------+
|  x|   15|            [15]|
|  x|   10|        [15, 10]|
|  x|   10|    [15, 10, 10]|
|  x|   25|[15, 10, 10, 25]|
|  y|   10|            [10]|
|  y|   20|        [10, 20]|
|  y|   20|    [10, 20, 20]|
+---+-----+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @ManojSingh is perfect. I still want to share my point of view, so that I can be helpful.

The `Window.partitionBy('key')` works like a `groupBy` for every different `key` in the dataframe, allowing you to perform the same operation over all of them.

The `orderBy` usually makes sense when it's performed in a sortable column. Take, for example, a column named `'month'`, containing all the months in a year (1,2,3...12) and another one named `'price'` with the price for each month. If you want to the sum, the mean or whatever for every month and all the preceding ones, you use the `orderBy`. This is good for example to calculate the variation between the months.